# How to show a form in PyQGIS?

Tags: python, qgis, plugins

I am working with python plugins for QGIS same as **rt sql layer**.I developed the plugin and copied into local repository  **C:\Documents and Settings\comp90.qgis\python\plugins**.
When i open QGIS exe,connection is established ans all the tables are listed.But when i try to open my query builder form,it gives me error saying

```
QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
TypeError: QDialog(QWidget parent=None, Qt.WindowFlags flags=0): argument 1 has unexpected 
type 'QgisInterface'
```

My code of query builder form is a follows:

```
class DlgQueryBuilder(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self,db=conn, iface=None, parent=None):


            QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

            self.setupUi(self)

            self.db = db
```

What is **QgisInterface**?? help me out...!!

this form is called from **ManagerWindow.py** file as below:

```
def queryWindow(self):
            """ show sql window """
            dlg = DlgQueryBuilder(self, self.db, self.iface)
            if dlg.exec_():
                    self.close()
```

Comment: We need to see all code. Especially the part that calls the form.

Comment: @underdark-i added the code..just check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't pass *self* when creating an object:

```
dlg = DlgQueryBuilder(self.db, self.iface)
```